# Opening and closing multiform application compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

So I've been browsing for some time on this topic of what is the best way to do this. I am working with scan guns and building an application for one. My application has many different menu screens as you can see from the picture.[image: Form Layout]
My application seems to freeze up on one scan gun but not another although they have almost exactly similar hardware. I thought perhaps it is because I am not closing any of my forms once created. I build the instance within the form when calling it and then call the show method.

AssetsMenu.GetInstance().Show();

When I am done with the form or wish to display the next form I call the Hide method form within that form.

this.Hide();

Am I going about this incorrectly or is the best way to reuse forms. Should I be using AssetsMenu.GetInstance().Close() instead and just create a new form when I need to use this again?

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really a memory question.  Should you close them?  If you don't have enough memory to hold them all at one time, then yes.  Typically I run a "memory service" in all of my apps that will output to the debug memory conditions, especially when they get critical.  I'd suggest doing something similar and looking specifically at the device's memory load.  Open all of the Forms and see where it stands.  If you're really high (like 95%+) then you certainly could have a problem.

There could be a whole host of other things going on sucking up memory too, so it may not be Form-related at all.

Personally I'd use a stack for the Forms and as the user backs up, I'd close and dispose of them, but most apps I work on have a whole lot more Forms that what you're showing.

In the end you're going to have to profile and test with your app on your devices.  There's no hard and fast rule that says you have to close all Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem with my CF 4.5 Application. Instead of using several forms, I have just one Form and several unvisible "Panels" all over each other (you can find them in the VS toolbox). At the start of the Application, only the "LogIn" panel (and so its controls) is visible. After a user click on LogIn button and is verified, i set this panel to unvisible and the next one to visible and so on...

I dont think this i the most efficient way, but it solved my problem..